Normalizing a table with all info into different tables
Let's say I have the following table without normalization:
Design 1: Without normalization:

Design 2 : Considering Normalization
Here are some of the tables that are possible to come up with based on the above table info:
valueIDs: ( valueID, name ) --key=valueID
valueIDValues: ( valueID, numericalValue ) --key=(valueID, numericalValue)
valuePartialStorage: ( valueID, rowValue, color, PlateName, Barcode ) --key=(valudID, rowValue?)
valueDetailedStorage: ( valueID, selectedValue, availableCases ) --key-(valueID, selectedValue)

where valueID is the parent table and all other tables are child tables.
So the table would look like the following with the data:


As seen above, Table 3 is still having some duplicate values. So I wanted to know if I'm heading in the right direction? Do I need to split Table 3 into more tables where 2nd normal form condition is satisfied?

Normalization looks at the columns or their combinations meaning and ignores their values. For example, if the barcode value definitely defines the plate name value (i.e. these are 2 properties values of the same entity instance) then these columns may be moved to separate table. If the barcode and plate name are in practice separate entities linked as M:N then they'd be moved to separate tables + adjacency table, and table3 should be referenced on  this adjacency table. And if the duplication is random then table3 shouldn't be modified.

Thanks @Akina. If I have to keep the Table 3 as same as above, what key I should be using as none of the combination of keys will be able to uniquely identify a record with the current data in it.

I'd prefer synthetic autoincrement primary key.
